# How to attach debugger for Jooby2

Tags: java, maven, jooby

I am trying to attach the remote server to 8000 in intellij.

Also started the server in debugging mode using the command **mvn jooby:run -Dapplication.fork=true**

But, I am getting connection failed exception.

Comment: a stacktrace would be nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Thanks @jknack

Ref: https://github.com/jooby-project/jooby/issues/215

Run:     `mvnDebug jooby:run`

Where mvnDebug performs, `MAVEN_DEBUG_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000"`

This will attach the debugger on port 8000. Now open the ide and create remote debugger and attach it the port 8000.

**Debugger mode**: Attach to the remote JVM